# How to count the appearance of each word in text

Tags: go, nlp

Or the question could also be:
What is the Go way of getting bags of words?

For example, if the input is

`"This is a big apple tree. I love big big apple! 42"`

then how do I get an output of map with count of each word (and, if conveniently, do some simple string parsing along the way such as only keep letters and lower them):

`{this=1, is=1, a=1, big=3, apple=2, tree=1, i=1, love=1}`

---

The simple version of some Kotlin code can be like:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val inputText = "This is a big apple tree. I love big big apple! 42"

    val map = inputText.replace("[^a-zA-Z]+".toRegex(), " ") // only keep letters
            .trim()
            .toLowerCase()
            .split(" ")
            .groupingBy { it }
            .eachCount()

    println(map)
}
```

gives output `{this=1, is=1, a=1, big=3, apple=2, tree=1, i=1, love=1}`

I would like to know what's the equivalent Golang way of doing something like this.
Hopefully it is fast, easy to read as well.

Comment: Go's way is the obvious way: https://play.golang.org/p/XPTJ5q_-mSv

Comment: @Peter Thank you Peter, I am new to Go and I heard Go is easy to read. Just would like to get a better taste of Go doing stuff like these, as I am thinking about migrate some project from Java to Go. BTW is it possible to do regular expression operations  in Go?

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/

Comment: You should take the tour to get a feel for Go: https://tour.golang.org/

Answer (score 7):

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    text := "This is a big apple tree. I love big big apple! 42"
    fields := strings.FieldsFunc(text, func(r rune) bool {
        return !('a' <= r && r <= 'z' || 'A' <= r && r <= 'Z')
    })
    words := make(map[string]int)
    for _, field := range fields {
        words[strings.ToLower(field)]++
    }
    fmt.Println(words)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/6J-ptfCoJ8r

Output:

```
map[tree:1 i:1 love:1 this:1 is:1 a:1 big:3 apple:2]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It's pretty cool that you don't need to initialise all the zeros in map. 
BTW, do you know if it is simple to do make this piece of code run on multiple cores of CPU? Let's say if the text is super long or there are just too many texts in a very long lists? I know in java one can perhaps uses parallelstream together with some lambdas to achieve that. How to do this in go and is it easy?

If it is not too difficult then I am thinking about migrating a project from java/kotlin in Go.